# My lenovo g70-80 won't start past splash screen

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

When I turn on my lenovo G70-80, it would load the lenovo screen, but nothing past that. Also when I turn on my laptop it would beep 20 times before stopping. I've tried reinserting the ram, but no dice.anyone have any advice before I pay by to get it fixed.

Comment: How did you count the beeps? See https://support.lenovo.com/de/de/documents/ht062270 (switch the language if needed), I don't see 20 there.

Comment: The website points to power issues, but I'm still lost. The battery seems fine and it charges well, so I'm not sure what else it could be

Comment: Although it has a bent radiator at the side for what it's worth

Comment: "power issues" would point to the ac adaptor. Is it the right voltage? Amperage? have you tried another one to ensure the first one isn't dying on you? (power supplies are notorious for seeming to work fine, but actually delivering bad power). Additionally, does it do this when plugged in as well as on battery? Have you tried powering it on without the battery installed? Can you enter bios and reset to default settings?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the voltage or amperage is, or even how to get that info. The laptop does power on without the battery and with the charger plugged in, but it's the same problem when I had the battery in (stuck on splash screen with repeated beeping). finally, no I can't enter the bios.